# How to append text to an existing file?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

The following code helps me to parse the text of PPT slides and dump it into a csv file called Project_SI Feedback_temp_v3.csv. This file is supposed to be a template into which i want to dump the text whereas this code opens a new csv file called Project_SI Feedback_temp_v3.csv instead of writing it into the given template. Is there any way I could open an existing file rather than create a new one?

```
  Sub ExportTextToCSV()

  Dim oPres As Presentation
  Dim oSlides As Slides
  Dim oSld As Slide         'Slide Object
  Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
  Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
  Dim sTempString As String

  Dim PathSep As String
  Dim Quote As String
  Dim Comma As String
  iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number

  #If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
  #Else
    PathSep = "\"
  #End If

  Quote = Chr$(34)
  Comma = ","

  Set oPres = ActivePresentation
  Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

  'Open output file
  ' NOTE:  errors here if original PPT file hasn't been saved
  Open oPres.Path & PathSep & "Project_SI Feedback_temp_v3.csv" For Output As iFile

  For Each oSld In oSlides    'Loop thru each slide
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide

      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
          sTempString = sTempString & ",,," & Quote & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & Quote & Comma
      End If

    Next oShp

    ' print the result to file:
    Print #iFile, sTempString
    sTempString = ""

  Next oSld

  'Close output file
  Close #iFile
```

Comment: Look at the Language Reference for this method. More specifically, look at the `mode` parameter. `Append` is probably more appropriate for what you want.

Comment: What do you mean? Where do I append it?

Comment: Cindy Meister wanted you to have a look at the help page for the `Open` command. There are several possible `modes` in which a file can be opened. (Hint: The modes are: `Append, Binary, Input, Output, Random`

Comment: I've proposed an edit to your question's title, so it actually reflects what you're asking, as your original title did not ask a question.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I will take a look